# Same Wifi names keep messing with connection

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, mac-address

I just got a RasPi and I'm looking to replace the Windows PC that's doing the routing job. (To save electricity)

What I'm trying to do with it is make it connect to a wifi network using it's bssid(or mac address).

My adapter gets confused as to where it would connect (there are a lot of access points with the same name). It would usually throw a driver error.

How does one connect using bssid only, if that's possible? I tried to use wpa_supplicant, but it seems that the other AP's are still messing with my connection.. Something wrong with my configuration maybe?

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# wireless interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 wpa-ap-scan 1
 wpa-scan-ssid 1
wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf


##CONFIG FOR INTERNET SHARING/ROUTER
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  network 192.168.0.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  address 192.168.0.1
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  gateway 192.168.0.1
```

wpa_supplicant.conf file (wpa.conf for me)

```
network={
bssid=00:0E:XX:XX:XX:XX
ssid="XXXXXXXXXX"
proto=WPA2
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="XXXXXXXXXX"
priority=1
}
```